# eGit history in eclipse only shows one commit

Tags: java, git, egit

So this has been happening for as long as I can remember and ended in me numerous times just giving up on Git, especially using eGit for Eclipse and java. Everytime I create a project, then go through team and set it up as a git repository, it is initiated as "foo NO-HEAD". So I'm like okay, maybe I just need to initialize a first commit ( I have been researching this "problem" for a long time and I've gotten so many comments, none of which work, and this was one of them) and when I do it seems to be successful. I initialize the first commit, call it Commit 0001, and the tag next to my project name changes to "foo master", so to me that says it was pushed to the master branch and in the history view it shows "commit 0001 lorem ipsum etc". Now the problem comes in on my next commit "commit 0002". After I push it, I look in my history view and find that I ONLY see "commit 0002 lorem ipsum etc", not both the first and second commits. Why is this?!

EDIT: I want to point out I do add all my files to the index using the staging view window. (drag from unstaged, to staged, and all files show a green plus mark so I know they are in the index)

Answer (score 0):

It may be that your *History* view is currently configured to only show commits for a specific file. If that file was only added in your second commit, only that commit would be shown.

To change the view to show all commits, select the repository icon from the top right of the view toolbar. See the section ["Working with the Filter Settings" in the EGit User Guide](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Working_with_the_Filter_Settings) for screenshots and explanations.

Comment: I should have specified, I have no filters enabled. And no its in the history viewer, no matter what should show a list of commits / branches and what not. This is why I am confused. Thank you for your response though @robinst

Comment: I still don't understand what the question/problem is. A screenshot of the problem would help.